# Daily Notification in Android not working

Tags: java, android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

I wanted my Application to send notification everyday to the user, following [this](https://ptyagicodecamp.github.io/scheduling-repeating-local-notifications-using-alarm-manager.html) link and doing everything as described. The app doesn't send notifications. The **buildLocalNotification** function is being triggered every 60 seconds, but no Notification is displayed. I kept an Interval of 2000 ms but android changed it to 60 Seconds.

**Logcat Message:**  Suspiciously short interval 2000 millis; expanding to 60 seconds Every 60 seconds the notification function is triggered.

This is my

**NotfBroadcastReceiver.class**

```
   import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class NotfBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Get notification manager to manage/send notifications


        //Intent to invoke app when click on notification.
        //In this sample, we want to start/launch this sample app when user clicks on notification
        Intent intentToRepeat = new Intent(context, SplashScreen.class);
        //set flag to restart/relaunch the app
        intentToRepeat.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        //Pending intent to handle launch of Activity in intent above
        PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, NotificationHelper.ALARM_TYPE_ELAPSED, intentToRepeat, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        //Build notification
        Notification repeatedNotification = buildLocalNotification(context, pendingIntent).build();

        //Send local notification
        NotificationHelper.getNotificationManager(context).notify(NotificationHelper.ALARM_TYPE_ELAPSED, repeatedNotification);
    }

    public NotificationCompat.Builder buildLocalNotification(Context context, PendingIntent pendingIntent) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float)
                        .setContentTitle("Workout Reminder")
                        .setAutoCancel(true);
        Log.d("DEBUG", "buildLocalNotification: "+"Notification");

        return builder;
    }
```

This is my
**AlarmBootReceiver.class**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AlarmBootReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            //only enabling one type of notifications for demo purposes
            NotificationHelper.scheduleRepeatingElapsedNotification(context);
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the code that turn notification on and off:**

```
   swnotf.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b)
            {
                if(b)
                {
                    Log.d("DEBUG", "onCheckedChanged: "+ "ON");
                    CommonFunctions.setSwitchState(getContext(),"ON");
                    NotificationHelper.scheduleRepeatingElapsedNotification(getContext());
                    NotificationHelper.enableBootReceiver(getContext());
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d("DEBUG", "onCheckedChanged: "+"OFF");
                    CommonFunctions.setSwitchState(getContext(),"OFF");
                    NotificationHelper.cancelAlarmElapsed();
                    NotificationHelper.disableBootReceiver(getContext());
                }
            }
        });
```

Please I have already spent THREE days trying other solutions and fixing this. I don't want to spend more time on this. Any help would be Appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: do you have an error on your logcat ?

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Do you know for sure the boot receiver is being triggered? Do you know how much of this is working as expected and where it actually begins to fail? Have you checked LogCat for warnings and / or errors? Anything beyond "app doesn't send notifications" which is so vague a description no one can help you.

Comment: Okay, so the function is being triggered but the notifications are not displayed. For debugging purpose, I kept an Interval of 2000 ms but Android changed it to 60 Seconds. Logcat Message: 2021-04-17 11:27:23.934 1279-10569/? W/AlarmManager: Suspiciously short interval 2000 millis; expanding to 60 seconds

Every 60 seconds the notification function is triggered. @dominicoder

Comment: @ShayKin No Errors

Comment: Is the broadcast called? If yes so you have a notification problem maybe the notification chanel I don't see the it in your code  try your code with and api < 26 if it's work then create a notification chanel for api >26

Comment: @ShayKin Yes, Every 60 Seconds.
 I'll try this and update. Thank You!

Comment: @ShayKin The Solution WORKED!!. Notification Channel was needed. Thankyou!